# Como descobrir o client ID nas notificações Web(webnotification)?

Tags: genexus

Utilizando o *datatype webnotification* tenho o método *notifyclient* que precisa de um *ID* do Browser cliente.

Como descubro qual é este *ID* para fazer uma notificação específica para uma página do cliente atual(logado) ?

Ou posso utilizar o *ID* da sessão do cliente ?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que usar o objeto Webnotification propriedade ClientId .

Para mais informações você pode conferir neste tópico :

[WebNotifications](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Web%20Notifications)

```
// Pega o ID do client Atual
    &Clientid = &webnotification.ClientId

    // Notifica apenas o Client(Browser atual)
    &webnotification.NotifyClient(&Clientid,&NotificationInfo)
```

Comment: Janelas POPUPS esta variável &ClientId tem que ser passada via parâmetro da janela anterior(a que chamou o popup)